# XSD to SQL Server conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, xsd, visual-studio-2013, sqlxml

I have a question in regards to the SQLXML for SQL Server.

My assignment is to convert an XSD file so that it magically "becomes" tables in the SQL Server database. I've looked around everywhere, on all the links I could possibly find, but nothing clicks. Everything is like a half-step of what I need to achieve.

I am not too familiar with Visual Studio, haven't done much else than running database queries and all the stuff one likes to do in a SQL Server database. Except for XML.

I figured that SQLXML from Microsoft's MSDN would be a good tool to have (and I believe it's already installed).

Any tips or solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic involved, and as it's homework/study I won't detail how to do it myself, but if you direct your research towards SQL's Bulk Load functionality it would seem to be what you need.

Read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/monicafrintu/archive/2007/06/12/how-to-create-tables-in-a-database-using-an-xsd-schema-and-sqlxmlbulkload.aspx?Redirected=true) for a brief "how to" guide.

Or this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225763%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for a detailed description of how to use it.