# How to add an XSD to SQL database project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, xsd

I have the following problem: I have little programming skills and this is the first time I've opened Visual Studio. My goal is to directly import an XSD schema into a preexisting SQL database or a new one. I already have the defined XSD, don't need to do it from scratch. I've researched the problem and found that is somehow possible but the workaround seems to be efficient only in previous versions of the Visual Studio.

Proposed answers: [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241258/xsd-to-sql-server-conversion) or the 
[walk through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193276(v=vs.100).aspx) proposed by Microsoft. Another option is this [tutorial/extensive explanation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76814/Generate-SQL-Database-Schema-from-XML-Part-File), but since I have no programming background and the last part of the tutorial was never published, it is not enough.

Do you have any ideas how to do that or if the aforementioned walk through works somehow?(I am stuck at the referencing step). Do you know any other ways to get past this in VS 2015?

Thanks!